# How does session work?

Tags: php, session, authentication

How do I reflect the correct user who login  on the form to show his/her user id using session function? For now nothing is reflected on the form where we want the Admin no field to show the user id of student who login.

```
 <?php session_start(); 
    $adminName = $_SESSION['txtName'];
    $adminPassword = $_SESSION['txtPassword'];
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/menupanel.css' />
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>      </script>

    <div id="header">
    <p align="center"><img src="images/logo.png" width="329" height="119" alt="TP Logo" /><br /></p>
    </div>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    include_once ('studentmenu.php');
    $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
    {
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $GPA = $_POST['GPA'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM student_details;");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT admin_no FROM student_details;");
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $result3 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO student_details"."(address,GPA)"."VALUES('$address','$GPA;");
        }
        ?>
<p>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
   <td width="410" align="center">Student Personal Data</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td height="170">
       <table>
         <form method= "post" action="studentpers_now.php">
         <tr>
           <td>Admission Number</td>
           <td><input name="Admin_no" type= "text" disabled="disabled" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['txtName'] ?>" size="40" readonly> 
          </td>
         </tr>
         </form>
         </table>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
```

Comment: I do  not understand your question but in the Form in the value you forgot `<?php` in the beginning and storing Passwort in session data is not a good idea

Comment: BTW, use `"VALUES('$address','$GPA')");` instead of `VALUES('$address','$GPA;");`

Comment: And btw, $_SESSION is not a function. It's a super global.

Comment: You ask a lot of questions and never accept any that have been given to you. Seems to me that there's no pleasing you. You want to know how sessions work, then [**read up on it** - RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) by reading the manual, and any [other manual](http://www.php.net) in regards to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the

Change it to:

```
<input name="Admin_no" type= "text" disabled="disabled" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['txtName'] ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_SESSION` values are stored in text files on your server and will be loaded every time you use sessions.
the `$_SESSION` construct can be used like an array.

```
// store in session
$_SESSION['adminId'] = 1;

// load from session
$variable = $_SESSION['adminId'];

// delete a session variable
unset($_SESSION['adminId']);

// delete a session
session_destroy();

// php echo short code
<input value="<?=$variable?>" type="text" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by stored in text files?

Comment: There is a folder on your web server where the session values are stored in text files. This can be checked by phpinfo(). Look for session.save_path.